# Python Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click a button. I tried many methods but did not work

So my question is, How can i click the "i agree" button?

[plaese see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIAas.png)

I tried this method

First:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id('introAgreeButton'))
vote = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]')
vote.click()
```

Second:

```
accepted = browser.find_elements_by_id('introAgreeButton')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", accepted )
```

Third(Classic):

```
accepted = browser.find_elements_by_id('introAgreeButton')
accepted.click()
```

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: @arundeepchohan selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="introAgreeButton"]"}

Comment: First check if it's in any iframes.

Comment: @arundeepchohan actually i added screenshot. could you please check?

Comment: Just check in the page source for any iframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use full xpath to get the iframe's full path. I got your script working like this:

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com')


driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[2]/span/div/div/iframe'))
element = driver.find_element_by_id('introAgreeButton')

element.click()
```

As you can see, I am using driver.switch_to.frame - inside this frame switch I will find the iframe element by using full xpath. You can find the full path by right clicking when inspecting it and selection "Copy -> Full Xpath"

I hope this helps, otherwise please ask :)

Answer (score 1):

The above reply from sykezlol didn't work for me, but this code did:

```
            browser.switch_to_default_content()
            browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0])
            browser.implicitly_wait(1)
            browser.find_element_by_id('introAgreeButton').click()
            browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

I'm using 'browser' instead of 'driver' here.

Comment: `browser.switch_to_default_content()` is now `browser.switch_to_default_content`